# Convert JSONObject to Map

Tags: java, dictionary, json

I have a `JSONObject` with some attributes that I want to convert into a `Map<String, Object>`

Is there something that I can use from the json.org or `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Why can't you use just the JSONObject?

Comment: @Marco Cali try using gson. It is a google library for handling json strings in java. It provides simple methods for conversion.

Comment: A `JSONObject` effectively is a map.  If you really need a Java `Map` either iterate through the JSONObject and populate your `Map` or use a JSON parsing library that does deserialization to Java classes. (Jackson, Gson)

Comment: It's useful to manage with Couchbase lite Android to populate a Document.

Comment: @Brian Roach: thanks, this is what I did.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

use Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) from http://json.org/

```java
HashMap<String,Object> result =
       new ObjectMapper().readValue(<JSON_OBJECT>, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: @MarcoCalì If you're using Jackson you wouldn't **need** to use a `JSONObject` and this does exactly what you're asking to do.

Comment: It's been removed 
Also any way of LinkedHashMap?

Comment: As far as I can see, @Manoranjan's answer is the only correct one here, even though going via string serialization and back to a map via GSON doesn't seem ideal. It's unfortunate that JSONObject can take a Map as input but not produce one as output.

Answer (score 52):

You can use Gson() (com.google.gson) library if you find any difficulty using Jackson.

//changed yourJsonObject.toString() to yourJsonObject as suggested by Martin Meeser

```
HashMap<String, Object> yourHashMap = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonObject, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: I am using gson 2.8.6 preview and you do not need the "yourJsonObject.toString()" any more, just the "yourJsonObject"

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 35):

This is what worked for me:

```
    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject jsonobj)  throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonobj.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = jsonobj.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }   
            map.put(key, value);
        }   return map;
    }

    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }
            else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }   return list;
}
```

Most of this is from this question: [How to convert JSONObject to new Map for all its keys using iterator java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243880/how-to-convert-jsonobject-to-new-map-for-all-its-keys-using-iterator-java)

Comment: this is the best solution without adding extra parsing libraries

Comment: Thanks @ir2pid. I tried all the other ways and couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 11):

The `JSONObject` has a method [`toMap`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#toMap--) which returns `Map<String,Object>`.

The Maven dependency used in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>${json.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find the latest `${json.version}` [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).

Answer (score 7):

The best way to convert it to `HashMap<String, Object>` is this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){}));
```

Answer (score 5):

Note to the above solution (from A Paul):
The solution doesn't work, cause it doesn't reconstructs back a HashMap< String, Object > - instead it creates a HashMap< String, LinkedHashMap >.

Reason why is because during demarshalling, each Object (JSON marshalled as a LinkedHashMap) is used as-is, it takes 1-on-1 the LinkedHashMap (instead of converting the LinkedHashMap back to its proper Object).

If you had a HashMap< String, MyOwnObject > then proper demarshalling was possible - see following example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, MyOwnObject.class);
HashMap<String, MyOwnObject> map = mapper.readValue(new StringReader(hashTable.toString()), mapType);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it in Kotlin:

```
mutableMapOf<String, Any>().apply {
           jsonObj.keys().forEach { put(it, jsonObj[it]) }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out these problems can be addressed by using

```
ObjectMapper#convertValue(Object fromValue, Class<T> toValueType)
```

As a result, the origal quuestion can be solved in a 2-step converison:

1. Demarshall the JSON back to an object - in which the `Map<String, Object>` is demarshalled as a `HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>`, by using bjectMapper#readValue().
2. Convert inner LinkedHashMaps back to proper objects

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class clazz = (Class) Class.forName(classType);
MyOwnObject value = mapper.convertValue(value, clazz);`

To prevent the 'classType' has to be known in advance, I enforced during marshalling an extra Map was added, containing `<key, classNameString>` pairs. So at unmarshalling time, the classType can be extracted dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;


Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

JSONObject rec = JSONObject.parseObject(<JSONString>);

map.put(rec.get("code").toString(), rec.get("value").toString());
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep it further simple

There is an out of the box function available by name `toMap()` which should do the job

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringAsJson);
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = jsonObject.toMap();
```