# How to convert JSONObject to Hashmap?

Tags: android, hashmap

```
String jsonString  = "{"name":"kd","isMe":"yes","time":"10:12 AM"},{"name":"you","isMe":"no","time":"10:12 AM"}";
```

JSONObject jValueObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

```
    Iterator<?> values = jValueObject.keys();
    while(values.hasNext()){
        String final_key = (String)values.next();
        String final_value = jValueObject.getString(final_key);
        if (final_value != "")
            map.put(final_key, final_value);

        if (!final_key.equals("")) {
            sbkeys.append(final_key).append(',');
        }
    }
    Log.e("Final_Map", String.valueOf(map));
    itemList = sbkeys.toString();
```

**Output : {name=kd,isMe=yes,time=10:12 AM}**

Comment: What is the error you are facing while running this code? Always be precise with your question.

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar I am getting that String jsonString from previous JSON string that was i converted into hashmap what get value if mu hashmap that value is my string. This string i wanted into the hashmap format but i get in iteration that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sbkeys = new StringBuilder();

            String key = (String) keys.next();
            String value = jObject.getString(key);

            try{
                JSONObject jValueObject = new JSONObject(value);
                Iterator<?> values = jValueObject.keys();

                while (values.hasNext()) {
                    String final_key = (String) values.next();
                    String final_value = jValueObject.getString(final_key);

                    if (!final_value.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        map.put(final_key, final_value);
                        sbkeys.append(final_key).append(',');
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.fillInStackTrace();
            }
            try {
               //// Your Code..
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorCode = "1";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Iterator<?> values = jValueObject.keys();
while(values.hasNext()) {
    String final_key = (String)values.next();
    String final_value = jValueObject.optString(final_key, "");
    if (!final_value.equals(""))
        map.put(final_key, final_value);
}
for (k : map.keySet()) {
    Log.d("Final_Map", "map[" + key + "] : " + map.get(k));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a duplicate question, 
please check these answers
[Convert JSONObject to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544973/convert-jsonobject-to-map)

use Jackson(http://jackson.codehaus.org/) from http://json.org/

```
HashMap<String,Object> result =
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(<JSON_OBJECT>, HashMap.class);
```

or

You can use Gson() (com.google.gson) library if you find any difficulty using Jackson.

```
HashMap<String, Object> yourHashMap = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonObject.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if its a json array that you need in the string then wrap your string in square brackets. (I'd expect you've escaped the double quotes as well).

```
    String jsonString  = "[{\"name\":\"kd\",\"isMe\":\"yes\",\"time\":\"10:12 AM\"},{\"name\":\"you\",\"isMe\":\"no\",\"time\":\"10:12 AM\"}]";
```

Now its a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject`. So to get a list of `Maps`,

```
JSONArray jValueArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
List<Object> listOfMaps = jValueArray.toList();
System.out.println(listOfMaps);
```

Prints:

```
[{isMe=yes, name=kd, time=10:12 AM}, {isMe=no, name=you, time=10:12 AM}]
```

Comment: I get String like"{"name":"kd","isMe":"yes","time":"10:12 AM"},{"name":"you","isMe":"no","time":"10:12 AM"}" . How can i add square brackets in that string.

Comment: `String jsonString  = "{\"name\":\"kd\",\"isMe\":\"yes\",\"time\":\"10:12 AM\"},{\"name\":\"you\",\"isMe\":\"no\",\"time\":\"10:12 AM\"}";
        jsonString = "[" + jsonString + "]";`

Comment: What is the error ? and which library are you using for JSON ?