# I would like to store some data of JSON response in the map

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an JSON response from the retrofit which look's like this:

```
  {
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.5299,
    "KRW": 1332.82,
    "MYR": 4.7006
  },
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2020-04-03"
}
```

And I wondering, How I may store some of that response In the Map? Could you provide me any hint, please?

I would like to have this data in map

```
    "CAD": 1.5299,
    "KRW": 1332.82,
    "MYR": 4.7006
```

Do I need to add this manually, or there's some faster way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSONObject to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544973/convert-jsonobject-to-map)

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. I'll post an answear to question to explain you my "requirements"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your json");
try {
    JSONObject rates = json.getJSONObject("rates");
    Iterator<String> cur = rates.keys();
    while(cur.hasNext()){
        map.put(cur.next(), rates.getDouble(cur.next()));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It works as a temporary solution, thank you for that. But I still looking for some more "automatic" solution.

Comment: Updated, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes that's it, but I don't know why, I don't have all of currencies