# How to convert JSONObject to Map in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hashmap, type-conversion

I get a `JSONObject` from the client and I want to convert it to a `Map` in Java Spring-Boot. Does anyone know a good approach with my data structure?

Json Object:

```
FilterObject: {
               "firstName":
                 {"filterType":"text","type":"contains","filter":"emma"},...
               }
```

Map to:

```
Map<String, ColumnFilter> filterMap;
```

```
public class ColumnFilter {
    private String filterType;
    private String type;
    private String filter;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544973/convert-jsonobject-to-map here the question was already solved

Comment: thanks I don't know how I missed that my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```
String columnFilterJson = "{\"firstName\":{\"filterType\":\"text\",\"type\":\"contains\",\"filter\":\"emma\"}}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, ColumnFilter> columnFilterMap = objectMapper.readValue(columnFilterJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, ColumnFilter>>() {});
```

Then with considering your `ColumnFilter` class has `toString()` method you can check result:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ColumnFilter> entry: columnFilterMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    ColumnFilter value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```